# Convergence of a sequence with two indexes

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Given a sequence $\{a_{n,p}\}$ with $(n,p)\in\Bbb{Z}×\Bbb{N}$.
Suppose $\lim\limits_{p\to+\infty}a_{n,p}=a_n\neq 0$ for each $n\in\Bbb{Z}$,
$\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}|a_n|<+\infty$ and 
$S=\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}a_n$.
Prove or disprove that:
$$\lim_{p\to+\infty}\sum_{n=-p}^{p}a_{n,p}=S.$$

Any hints will welcome!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take $a_{n,p} = \frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{(1+|n|)^2}$, where $p \in \mathbb{N}$ and $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then
$$
a_{n,p} \to  \frac{1}{(1+|n|)^2} :=a_n, \text{ as } p\to \infty,
$$
clearly $\sum_{n} |a_n| < \infty $, and let $S= \sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}{a_n}$. Then
$$
\sum_{n = -p}^p a_{n,p} = \frac{2p+1}{p}  +  \sum_{n=-p}^p  \frac{1}{(1+|n|)^2} \to 2 + S \text{ as } p \to \infty.
$$

Answer (score 3):

The assertion is false. Find a counterexample such that for each $n$, the sequence $a_{n,p}$ tends to $a_n$ as $p\to\infty$. But set things so that the larger $|n|$ is, the longer $a_{n,p}$ stays big -- say $a_{n,p}$ remains $1$ whenever $p\le|n|$, and only after $p>|n|$ will you allow $a_{n,p}$ to take the constant value $a_n$. (You should visualize this with a picture.)